# KitKat doesn't have translucide status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

From what I know, the translucide status bar was added in the KitKat version of Android, but my phone, which uses 4.4.2, has the normal (black) one. Why is that happening. Do I need to do something to activate this function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that depends on the app you have opened as opposed to simply changing the color of the status bar via your phone's settings. That said, the developer is in control as mentioned [here in Android docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI).